# How to understand this B+ Tree example

Tags: database

[image]

Hi, I'm learning about B+ Tree but having trouble to understand how it is formed.

As with the image above,

1) For the Root node, can one can randomly choose any value from the table? Shouldn't the root node be the medium value of the table, which is "Gold"?

2) Why is the first leaf node, (Brandt & Califieri & Crick) appear as the front pointer of the "Einstein node"?

I'm having trouble understanding it, since what I know to be a B+Tree should be formed as

[image]

Comment: For the second part of your question, it just looks like the leaf nodes are sorted, and have a linked list running through them.

Comment: ohhhh I was focusing too much on the table, which was sorted with the number of the professors after all. While the Tree itself is ordered as with the alphabetical order of the names. Am I right?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge on B+ trees to venture an answer, but if you look closely, you'll see that by choosing `Mozart` as the root node, the resulting B+ tree is _balanced_ on both sides.  So while `Mozart` may not be the alphabetically "middle" node, it sort of is the middle node with regard to the balance of the tree.